# Symfony Sonata SEO custom sql query with LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, yaml, sonata

I am using Sonata SEO on a Symfony 4 project.

`sonata-project/seo-bundle: ^2.7`

In my `config/packages/sonata_seo.yaml` file I have defined a custom SQL query to generate the sitemap with like so:

```
sitemap:
    doctrine_orm:
        - { connection: doctrine.dbal.default_connection, route: catch_all, parameters: {path: null}, query: "SELECT `path`, `updated_at` AS `lastmod`, 'weekly' AS `changefreq`, '0.5' AS `priority` FROM `pages` WHERE `published` = 1 AND `path` NOT LIKE('checkout/%') AND `path` NOT LIKE('bills/%%')" }
```

For easier reading (yaml forces me to have this in one line) here is the query:

```
SELECT `path`, `updated_at` AS `lastmod`, 'weekly' AS `changefreq`, '0.5' AS `priority` 
FROM `pages` 
WHERE `published` = 1 AND `path` NOT LIKE('checkout/%') AND `path` NOT LIKE('bills/%')
```

Basically I am using `WHERE NOT LIKE` to exclude certain pages from the sitemap being generated.

If I run the query in mysql directly it works as expected.

If I run it via the sonata seo command line utility like so:

```
php bin/console sonata:seo:sitemap '/path/to/sitemap/folder' 'https://dev.test'
```

I get this error:

> The parameter "\') AND `path` NOT LIKE(\'bill/" must be defined.

I've tried to escape various characters such as the `'` and the `%` that I suspected of causing the problem by prefixing a `\`, however that gives me errors like this one:

> Found unknown escape character "\%"

How do I properly escape this query within yaml so that it will run?

Comment: You could say `LEFT(path, 9) != 'checkout/'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the `%`, which is a special char in yaml.

So there's two ways to get this to work:

To escape it, it needs to be preceded by another `%` so:

```
AND `path` NOT LIKE('checkout/%%')
```

Alternatively you can avoid using the `%` as per Jared's comment and instead do:

```
LEFT(path, 9) != 'checkout/'
```